# Trouble understanding how best to setup the bare repository with CMS on server

Tags: git, repository, git-bare

I have a DEV server running our CMS and I would like to pull from and push to a repository in the CMS install - but I get errors because I'm trying to push to a non-bare repository (I've cloned this remote repository locally).

But from what I understand, a bare repository doesn't actually contain files which is obviously going to be a problem for viewing the CMS - not sure if this is correct?

Sorry if this is easy, I've been reading a lot of answers here but am still having trouble understanding how to set up my local and remote repositories when the remote needs files in it.

Also, I'm using Tower as I'm not too hot with git in the command line.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) has a good run-down on how this is done.

The idea is to push to a bare repo (one that does not have a working directory), and checkout to your web folder in a `post-receive` hook. Once you have that, you can push your updates to the bare repo with a simple `git push <remote_name>`, and that will update your web root.

With that setup you have:

- Your local repo - completely normal git repo you can work in
- The server's bare repo - all the git data, but no checked out files
- The server's web root/CMS folder - not a git repo, but contains one checked out revision.

That keeps the git stuff out of your web root, so that it contains only your CMS files. Makes things cleaner.

Comment: So I'd have a normal repo in the CMS directory, a normal repo on my local machine but would pull and push to another bare repo on the server that contains a post-receive hook which would automatically copy to and from the CMS repo?

Comment: The CMS doesn't really have a repo of its own. It's the complement to a bare repo if you will. The bare repo has the history/git stuff, the checkout location only has one revision checked out, no other git stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I agree with you that getting you head around git is a steep learning curve. Having been through it in recent memory. We had a guy called Jerremy skinner who knows his stuff - his video guide to getting going with git is here http://www.ava.co.uk/git - the first one is about 5 mins.

Comment: Thanks Ian, will definitely check out those videos. This aspect to git does seem overly complicated at this point - I would've thought a lot of people would need to push into a repo that is also a CMS or even a live site? Anyway, thanks heaps - Cheers, Ben